# Duplicate Keras Model but Remove Hidden Layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am attempting to automatically optimize a Keras model by removing BatchNormalization layers. I can perform the necessary mathematical operations for folding, but I need to iterate through the model and create a new one without the BatchNormalization layers.

Here is the Keras code that describes a basic model with a node with multiple outputs and inputs:

```py
input = Input(shape=(28,28,1))
layer = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), name='C0', activation=None)(input)
layer = Activation('relu')(layer)

x = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), name='C2', activation=None)(layer)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
y = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), name='Cy1', activation=None)(layer)
y = BatchNormalization()(y)
y = Activation('relu')(y)

x = concatenate([x, y])
x = Flatten(name='flatten')(x)
out = Dense(10, activation='softmax', name='classifier')(x)
```

Remember, in the application, I won't have this code here, but I will be able to iterate through the model.

I have attempted to use `layer._outbound_nodes` to find the next layers, but I cannot figure out how to create a search algorithm that can search all branches and recreate the structure.

I already know that `model.layers.pop()` returns a [shallow copy of the list](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22479#issuecomment-424577448) so it does not modify the model.

EDIT:
I found a way to remove a batch normalization layer from `plot_model`. It takes editing the layers before and after the batch normalization along with the batch normalization inbound and outbound nodes

```
bn_in = model.get_layer('batch_normalization_4')._inbound_nodes
bn_out = model.get_layer('batch_normalization_4')._outbound_nodes

model.get_layer('C2')._outbound_nodes=bn_out #set output of C2 equal to output of BN
model.get_layer('activation')._outbound_nodes=bn_in #set input of activation equal to input of BN

#disconnect batchnorm layer
model.get_layer('batch_normalization')._outbound_nodes=[]
model.get_layer('batch_normalization')._inbound_nodes=[]
```

[image: Batch Normalization removed from linkage but still in graph]
I still want to find a way to remove the BatchNorm layer from the Model entirely.